# why I can't use footnote(insert) in nested boxes?

Tags: footnotes, plain-tex

Sometimes, I need insert footnotes in nested boxes, but it seems that I can't use footnotes in nested boxes.

```
% ok
\hbox{a\footnote{$^1$}{a footnote}}
```

but not this

```
% won't get a footnote
\hbox{a\hbox{b\footnote{$^1$}{a footnote}}}
```

In TeXbook, it said

> The `\footnote` macro should be used only in `paragraphs` or `hboxes` that are
>   contributed to TeX's main vertical list; insertions will be lost if they occur
>   inside of boxes that are inside of boxes. Thus, for example, you should not try to put
>   a `\footnote` into a subformula of a math formula. But it's OK to use footnotes within
>   `\centerline`(it is like the first example).

so, why I can't use footnotes in nested boxes(the second example)? the reason behind the scenes? then, how can I use footnotes in nested boxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When TeX's page breaker splits off a chunk of the current page and puts it in box 255 for the output routine to assemble with page head and foot etc, it also make available (in each allocated insertion box) any *insertions* that correspond to insertion nodes in the main vertical list that has just been split to form box 255. (Ignoring complications about split insertions where footnotes may go over more than one page.)

Insertion (and mark) nodes *migrate* from horizontal lists to the surrounding vertical list, so if you put a `\footnote` in a paragraph, the node is initially in the horizontal list being built but when the paragraph is split into lines it *migrates* out of the horizontal list and is placed in the vertical list just after the hbox with the line of text (and before any inter-line glue).  However nodes never migrate out of explicit boxes such as `\hbox` you would have to `\unhbox` the contents to allow the nodes to escape and then migrate into a vertical list.

Insertion nodes that never migrate to the main vertical list are never seen by the output routine, and the saved content never appears in the accessible boxes such as `\box\footins` to be used by the output routine macros when making up the page.

You can of course make the footnote mark at the point you want the mark and then migrate the insertion by hand by placing the `\footnotetext` at a point that is not enclosed by a box.

Comment: Thanks, now I know the reason which I don't find in TeXbook. So happy :-)

Comment: @TimothyLi look up migration in the index, that's the main indexed concept here.

Comment: I see it in the index! thanks, I will read those pages carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is related to why footnotes inside `minipages` etc. need to be handled specially.  Inside the nested box, you just place the footnote marker; then from outside the box, you add the text.  Though with this approach, each time you place the footnote marker, you need to make sure you've advanced the footnote counter first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

This is the first footnote.\footnote{Just a simple note.}
\lipsum[1]

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
    There is a footnote here.\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotemark[\thefootnote]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}
\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{A footnote from within a box.}


There is a footnote here too.\footnote{Hello again.}
\lipsum[3]

\hbox{This is the outside box \hbox{I in the inner\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotemark[\thefootnote] box}}
\footnotetext[\thefootnote]{a footnote from within nested  boxes.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Footnotes inside minipage are saved in a box. The normal footnote of LaTeX instead is working with `\insert` ("a kind of box").

Comment: This works well for a parbox too. As a parbox seems to swallow the footnotes created from within, you can even say `\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotemark[\thefootnote]{something}` and thus get rid of the warning about an empty anchor.